# Issue in Login ScrollView.. ParentBottom elements also pop up with SoftKeyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".Login" >


  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_main" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_textBottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"        
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="@string/label_copyright"
    android:textColor="@color/text_grey" />

     <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv_Login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/logo"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_Login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        //Inside this manage two editText for userId, Password


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Also In manifest for Login, I set

```
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

My Issue is when softKeybord popup.. the bottom text(tv_textBottom) moves up with keyboard..I tried it many ways, need scrollview and placed the parent bottom text in parent down itself.. 
  Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Try out with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` @Joyal

Comment: @GrIsHu...I tried with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" or android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing".. bottom text is not popup with softkeyboard..Tat is fne..bt my scrollview is not working with this  fix

Comment: Try out with `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified"`

Comment: @GrIsHu.. i tired android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified".. same as above bottom text is popup with keyboard

Comment: @GrIsHu I am having the same trouble, referred [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32095820/1479511), and also tried adjustNothing and found scrollView doesn't work with that, unluckily.

Comment: @Joyal I am facing the same [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32095820/1479511), if you find any solution to the problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this
**AndroidManifest.xml**
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".Login" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_main" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_Login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_Login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            //Inside this manage two editText for userId, Password


        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_textBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/label_copyright"
        android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @haresh.. i tired this now the text pop up issue is solved.. Scrollview is not working by this fixing

Comment: @Haresh..thank you to look in to this.. I tired as u told..still the issue is there ..textview  android:id="@+id/tv_textBottom" popup with the keyborad

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" try this