# android making layout scrollable when soft keyboard open, but not shifting it upwards

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollable, android-keypad

This is my screen, with one button hidden behind the keyboard.

**I want exactly like this, but scrollable. -**

[image: keyboard open with one button hidden behind]

Whenever, the keyboard gets opened, I want to make look it the same as in image. But, instead to make it scrollable, so that the user can scroll to view the bottom part of the screen (including button), even when the keyboard is open.

I tried -

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

but, this shifts the bottom part upwards, whenever keyboard is opened.

as in this image -

***I don't want this*** - (shifting of `Create Account` button upwards, when keypad is opened)

[image]

> **CREATE ACCOUNT** button must be visible after scrolling.

Here is the layout -

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:fillViewport="true"

    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:weightSum="10"

        >
        <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_username_or_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/et_hint_username_or_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_pswd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/et_hint_password"
                    android:password="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/btn_sign_in"
                    android:background="@color/lighter_orange"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/or"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_take_a_peek"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/btn_take_a_peek"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:background="@color/button_gray"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/forgot_password"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_gray"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_create_account"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/btn_create_account"
                android:background="@color/button_very_light_orange"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Please help me to fix this up.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unluckily, not.

Comment: i have an iphone, so i know ios developers are capable of implementing it because i see it in apps, but i've never had an android, so i'm not even sure if it's something that exists on that platform

Comment: hey you got any solution?

Comment: I have the same problem, could you fix it?

Answer (score 14):

Add this input mode in your manifest file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same Problem and solved it.

Add this to your class inside the `<activity>` tags in the AndroidManifest in your Class:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
```

or:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.app.app.RegisterScreen"
        android:parentActivityName="com.app.app.LogInScreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">

    </activity>
```

Example:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.app.yourapp.LogInScreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">

</activity>
```

This works for me.

Comment: Yes, tried that, but as I mentioned, it shifted the bottom button upwards  when keypad gets opened, which I do not want. I just want to make it scrollable.

Comment: you mean it shifts up the button so the last button is over the soft keyboard?

Comment: have you tried to put the scrollview inside an relativelayout?

Comment: Not yet, what must be the height of both - RelativeLayout and ScrollView?

Comment: i set relative fill and scrollView wrap

Comment: maybe you try to use adjustPan as i added in my answer... so you have to try stateHidden|adjustPan

Comment: what about in Fragment?

Comment: are you able to fix it?

Comment: @NarendraSingh have you fix it? please reply

Answer (score 0):

Make the root of your view

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It's working for me in my application, can you share your layout xml?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have the singleLine attribute in my editText, and the fillViewport in the scrollview but I can't see other differences. :(

Answer (score 0):

Refer this to choose the appropriate mode for your screen
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: Tried all of them...but none is working as per my requirement :(

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will helpful for you Already I have designed such type of layout. I did not edited your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.clearfly.groupfone"
 android:id="@+id/registration_view"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@android:color/white"
 android:fillViewport="true"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivProfilePicture"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/firstname_edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:hint="First Name"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/lastname_edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:hint="Last Name"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email_edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:hint="email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLength="255"
                    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/verify_password_edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:hint="Verify pwd"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: let me try this thing

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra I am sure it will work because working in my app just I have changed string name and color etc..

Comment: Hey, what about the manifest, do I need to edit something there for this activity?

Comment: I tried the same code...but its shifting the inputs upwards when keyboard is opened.

Comment: I do not want to shift them upward.

Comment: But, I do not want to move the whole view up or down on the basis of showing / hiding the keyboard.

Comment: Please see this link I hope it will help you same he was facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410257/layout-of-the-screen-moves-up-when-keyboard-is-displayed

Comment: your code is somewhat working, but I need to make the childviews center vertically, but I am unable to do so.

Comment: Great, Let me try to make as same your views if my code working as per the concept plz accept

Comment: when trying to make it center align, the layout / view gets shifted up (with keypad) :( I want to make them remain in center, even after the keypad opens.

Comment: I also tried adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" in manifest with your code. That stopped the shifting upwards, but at the same time also stopped scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and also I have the same issue [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115416/issue-in-login-scrollview-parentbottom-elements-also-pop-up-with-softkeyboard?noredirect=1#comment52118411_20115416)

Here I make some correction in your code and values were codes as dummy(strings, colors ect)... Code Snippet is:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_username_or_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="HAI"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_pswd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="HH"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#5465"
                android:text="sigin"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="ORR"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_take_a_peek"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#ff8f43"
                android:text="sfse"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Forgot"
                android:textColor="#ec0974" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_create_account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffd250"
        android:text="Create Accounr"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Also set the below parameter to your activity in you Manifest

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

**Edited as in view outer layer is Relative layout inside a scrollview and i managed the Create Account button as parent bottom.

Please try it in a real device.

Try this and give your feedback !!
Happy Coding..

Comment: I tried your code, but scrolling not working in this case.

Comment: @DroidWorm Narendra  .. I tired the above code and its works fine. Please check the  above xml file , i made some layout changes from your code. Also android:windowSoftInputMode in your manifest. Dont miss anything and try to run in real device.

Comment: Yes, I exactly copied your xml, also added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to the manifest. But, I am unable to scroll the view / layout in case of keypad

Comment: Please recheck it once

Comment: I am also facing same problem. I tried above solution but scrolling not working.

Answer (score 0):

old questioned with which I struggled today, What worked for me was to remove "android:windowSoftInputMode" from manifest and activity XML and, instead of making the root scroll view, make the scroll view child of root-

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MyActivity"
        >
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/my_scrollview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <!-- your xml code here. -->
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to answer, but may help someone.

I was also facing this issue and ended up hiding button which we don't want to be visible on keyboard up. So in this case it's "create account" which is to be hidden on keyboard up and show on keyboard down.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to scroll (only when keyboard pop up), you will need adjustResize warped in scrollView, but adjustResize automatically shifted the page for you.

may be you could scroll the page to the desired position after the adjustResize occur

````
// this is the edittext
        this.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                int[] absLocation = new int[2];
                int absHeight = absLocation[1];

                if (hasFocus) {
                        ScrollView sv = // get the id of your scroll view

                        if (sv != null){
                            view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    sv.smoothScrollBy(0, number); // how much you want to scroll to
                                }
                            }, 700);  // some delay after the adjust Resize

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    ```
````