# Trouble in design when click the edittext in popup?

Tags: android, design-patterns

problem :When i click editext in popup , the layout of the screen moves up.

Here original layout,
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDGnT.png)

After Clicking editext in popup,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP0lw.png)

I have to search and get the solution . but this is only suitable for activity. Im using fragemt so how can i solve my issues,

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573629/keyboard-windowsoftinputmode-fragment
please check

Comment: if this doesnt work you need to change your layout file

Comment: Where i put in this line ,getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.softInputMode.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

Comment: in your fragment

Comment: I know fragment . im asking put initialize fragment  (or) popup view

Comment: while initializing

Comment: Having this error , Error:(361, 84) error: non-static variable softInputMode cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: your fragmnets is declared as static?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your fragment class,

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```